# Vscode create java project only two folders lib and bin

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, .class-file

When I create a java project, there are only two folders lib and src, and not files such as .classpath or .project, I know that is integrated into the terminal of vscode
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fl8r.png)

But I want to output the class file to the bin folder of the current folder instead of the path in the picture, I hope to make my project run in eclipse, can anyone tell me what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Maven or Gradle based project instead of a freestyle structure, it will be recognized in all IDEs including Eclipse as you expected.

Check the [Java Build tutorial from the officila VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build).